# Creating substrings from text file

Tags: objective-c, string, eof

I have a text file that contains two lines of numbers, all I want to do is turn each line into a string, then add it into an array (called fields).  My problem arrises when trying to find the EOF character. I can read from the file with no problem: I turn it's content into a NSString, then pass to this method.

```
-(void)parseString:(NSString *)inputString{

NSLog(@"[parseString] *inputString: %@", inputString);

//the end of the previous line, this is also the start of the next lien
int endOfPreviousLine = 0;

//count of how many characters we've gone through
int charCount = 0;

//while we havent gone through every character
while(charCount <= [inputString length]){
    NSLog(@"[parseString] while loop count %i", charCount);

    //if its an end of line character or end of file
    if([inputString characterAtIndex:charCount] == '\n' || [inputString characterAtIndex:charCount] == '\0'){

        //add a substring into the array
        [fields addObject:[inputString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(endOfPreviousLine, charCount)]];
        NSLog(@"[parseString] string added into array: %@", [inputString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(endOfPreviousLine, charCount)]);

        //set the endOfPreviousLine to the current char count, this is where the next string will start from
        endOfPreviousLine = charCount+1;
    }

    charCount++;

}
NSLog(@"[parseString] exited while.  endOfPrevious: %i, charCount: %i", endOfPreviousLine, charCount);
```

}

The contents of my text file look like this:

```
123
456
```

I can get the first string (123) no problem.  The call would be:

```
[fields addObject:[inputString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)]];
```

Next, I make the call for the second String:

```
[fields addObject:[inputString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(4, 7)]];
```

But I get an error, and I think it is because my index is out of bounds.  Since the index starts from 0, there is no index 7 (well I think its supposed to be the EOF character), and I get an error.

To sum everything up:  I don't know how to deal with an index of 7 when there are only 6 characters + the EOF character.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` to get the effect that you are looking for:

```
-(NSArray*)parseString:(NSString *)inputString {
    return [inputString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is to use [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"] and get the array of numbers.

Example:
Use the following code to get the lines in an array

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathForResource:@"aaa" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: path];
NSArray *lines = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"str = %@", str);
NSLog(@"lines = %@", lines);
```

The above code assumes that you have a file called "aaa.txt" in your resources which is plain text file.